# unable to call a function in python with pointer parameter

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
class X:
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        ###########
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        shotcut_list = [
            "Key.f9",
            "Key.f2",
            "Key.f3",
            "Key.f4",
            "Key.f5",
            "Key.f6",
            "Key.f7",
            "Key.f8",
            "Key.f1",
            "Key.f10",
            "Key.f11",
            "Key.f12",
        ]
        combo.addItems(shotcut_list)
        global shortcut
        global cptext
        shortcut = combo.currentText()
        combo.setGeometry(350, 120, 120, 30)
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onChanged)
        # Create textbox
        self.textbox = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(20, 160)
        self.textbox.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textbox.resize(500, 205)
        self.setGeometry(70, 70, 540, 388)
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, text):
        global shortcut
        shortcut = text

    def update(self):
        self.textbox.insertPlainText(cptext)
        print(cptext)

    def print_key(*self):
        print(self[0])
        if str(self[1]) == shortcut:
            global cptext
            cptext = pc.paste()
            keyboard.type(cptext)
            self.textbox.insertPlainText(
                cptext
            )  # cannot call the text box using self
```

Comment: Is it because Python doesn't have pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `*self` is not a "pointer parameter" in Python, it's tuple unpacking for a variable number of arguments. Try

```
    def print_key(self, key):
        print(self)
        if str(key) == shortcut:
             # ...
```

instead (or if `print_key` is being sent more args you don't care about, `print_key(self, key, *args)`)...

Comment: def print_key(*self):
        print(self[0])
        if str(self[1]) == shortcut:
            global cptext
            cptext = pc.paste() 
            keyboard.type(cptext)
            self.textbox.insertPlainText(cptext)


    def key(self):    
        listener = Listener(on_press=self.print_key)
        listener.start()

Comment: @AshfaqueKhan I'm not sure what to make of that comment.

Comment: thanks a lot man , i am starting new in this great help